# Remove everything after a character from each line and return what's left

Tags: php

So let's say I have the following text:

`This is line number 1.
This is my line number 2.
This is his line number 3.
This is her line number 4.
This is their line number 5.`

I want to remove the word `number` and everything following it and return what's left (on separate lines, of course).

I hope this is possible and I didn't over-complicate the question, thanks!

Comment: I have tried this.
`substr($variable, 0, strpos($variable, "number"));`
But it just removed everything after `number`, like, all the lines and kept the first line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

strstr() is made for you, together with explode

```
$string = 'This is line number 1.
This is my line number 2.
This is his line number 3.
This is her line number 4.
This is their line number 5.';

$ex = explode('.',$string);
var_dump($ex);

foreach ($ex as $x) {
    echo strstr($x, 'number',true)."<br>";
}
```

Comment: This worked like a charm, thanks so  much.

I'll accept your answer in 6 minutes, again, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can just use strpos to find the word `number` and then substring the text (all in loop for each line)

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php. 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php
exploade the text after dots and loop on the resulting array. Hope it helps, i mon the pnone

Comment: How can I exactly loop it for each line?

Answer (score 0):

So here is the working Example:

```
$string = "This is line number 1";
$pos = strpos($string, "number");
    if ($pos == false) {
        print "Not found\n";
    } else {
        print "Found!\n";
        print substr($string, $pos);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

str_replace("number ", "",$actualstring) would work fine as well.